# React Native - unexpected token static propTypes when running assmbleRelease, babel plugin doesnt work

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I'm trying to compile a release apk in React Native using either
"react-native run-android --variant=release"  or
from ./android:
"./gradelw assmbleRelease"

I keep getting the following error:

```html
> :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

 ERROR  Failed to compile.

./node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/src/StyleProvider.js 10:19
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| export default class StyleProvider extends React.Component {
>   static propTypes = {
|     children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,

...
```

I've installed this plugin:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties.html

and added it to my babel.config.js:

```html
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],   
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
  ]
};
```

I've tried creating also a .babelrc file and setting it up. didn't work.
I tried configurating babel through package.json and also it didn't work.

I've tried doing

"react-native start -- --reset-cache"

but nothing helped. I keep getting the same error.
I know the babel.config.js is being read because if I mess around with it I see that the build fails for other reasons.
but a strange thing is that if I remove the file completely, I still get the original error (missing "static propTypes" thing).

why doesn't the plugin work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happened, but removing "haul" did the trick.

"npm uninstall --save-dev haul" 
and remove the added config in app/build.gradle:

```html
project.ext.react = [
    cliPath: "node_modules/haul/bin/cli.js"
]
```